# No puedo conectar el Driver de Sqlite en Java

Tags: java, sqlite

Soy nuevo en esto y he intentado de todo y ya no entiendo que hacer.Necesito que ingrese los datos a la base de Sqlite, pero me arroja error del driver, que este no se encuentra. Tengo estos codigos:

RegistroDAO.java que es el codigo que conecta a la base de datos.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.File;

public class RegistroDAO {
private Connection connection;

public RegistroDAO(String url) throws SQLException{
    String libDir = new File("lib").getAbsolutePath();
    System.setProperty("java.class.path", System.getProperty("java.class.path") + File.pathSeparator + libDir + File.separator + "sqlite-jdbc-3.41.2.1.jar");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + url);
}

public void insertarRegistro(String edificio, double peso) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO registros (edificio, peso) VALUES (?,?)"
    );
    statement.setString(1, edificio);
    statement.setDouble(2, peso);
    statement.executeUpdate();
}

public void cerrarConexion() throws SQLException{
    connection.close();
}
}
```

Tambien este otro codigo que solicita el ingreso de datos por parte del usuario y los envia a la base utilizado el Registro:

```
   import java.sql.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;


   public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese el peso del desecho: ");
        double peso = scanner.nextDouble();

        scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Ingrese el nombre del edificio: ");
        String edificio = scanner.nextLine();

        try{
            RegistroDAO registroDAO = new RegistroDAO("mi_basedatos.db");
            registroDAO.insertarRegistro(edificio, peso);
            registroDAO.cerrarConexion();
            System.out.println("Registro insertado correctamente.");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al insertar el registro: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}    
}
```

El problema es que en la carpeta lib tengo el conector pero me sigue arrojando siempre este error:

```
   Error al insertar el registro: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:mi_basedatos.db
```

Tengo el conector sqlite-jdbc.3.41.2.1.jar dentro de la carpeta lib.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué manejador de dependencias usas: Maven, Gradle? ¿O pusiste el driver a mano? En cualquiera de los casos, muéstranos el código que usas para incluir el archivo JDBC correspondiente, o si lo pusiste a mano, dinos exactamente qué archivo has descargado y qué versión y de dónde lo descargaste? Puede que no sea el archivo correcto o que no lo hayas puesto en el lugar correcto.

Comment: Hola, puse el driver a mano, siguiendo una guia, eso es todo lo que tengo, el codigo esta ahi en el RegistroDAO.java

Comment: ¿Qué archivo exactamente y de dónde lo descargaste? ¿No habrás puesto un `.zip` por ejemplo en vez del archivo `.jar` o algo así?

Comment: El archivo lo descargue de "https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/releases" es el sqlite-jdbc.3.41.2.1.jar, no esta en zip. lo coloque dentro de una carpeta llamada "lib" en la carpeta del proyecto, donde se encuentran los archivos "RegistroDAO.java" y "Main.java" que estan detallados arriba. Gracias

Comment: Además, pareces tener una confusión en este punto: `System.setProperty("java.class.path", System.getProperty("java.class.path") + File.pathSeparator + libDir + File.separator + "sqlite-jdbc-3.41.2.1.jar");` ¿Qué se supone que intentas hacer ahí? Si vas a usar propiedades para conectar, debes crear una instancia, agregar cada propiedad y luego pasar esa instancia a `DriverManager`, mira [este ejemplo](http://www.java2s.com/example/java-src/no-pkg/4ee/testdataencryptionintegrity-5b8f4.html).

Comment: Gracias. Ahora me funciona. lo raro es que al ejecutarlo en visual studio code lo ejecuta bien, completando el preceso, pero al ejecutarlo en terminal me arroja el mismo error.

Comment: Ya, debe ser por algún problema en la ubicación del `.jar` o en la definición del classpath o quién sabe... Te recomendaría que uses Gradle o Maven para manejar tu proyecto e incluir las dependencias. Haciendo las cosas a mano, si no hilas fino, puede ocurrir por ejemplo que cuando distribuyes la Aplicación ciertos archivos no se incluyen, resultando en un programa que no funciona en un entorno de producción. Gradle o Maven son una gran ayuda, para simplificar la inclusión de dependencia, e incluso para distribuir el programa final.